# Laptop with bad screen won't load Windows when it restarts

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader

I have a Dell Inspiron 5558 where the screen died just a few weeks past the warranty. Sigh. But all is not lost, and I have repurposed the machine as a home theater PC. Most of the time it works great... I have a Logitech K400+ and a Steam Controller connected to it, and love it.

But lately it does not reboot properly. The power light and keyboard backlight are on, and the back light behind the failed screen is turned on. But I've left it like that over night (and longer), and it never advances. I can't see where it's stuck, but I know it never gets a dhcp lease from the network, and I know it hasn't loaded Windows yet because certain windows shortcut keys that should make noise have no effect.

To "fix" the problem, I have to take out the hard drive and put it temporarily in a much older and less-powerful HP laptop. When I do this, the HP will boot up and after I shut down the HP properly I can put the drive back in the Dell and it will boot up normally... but this is a pain.

At first I thought the problem was Windows Updates, but recently I'm thinking it's something else. I've now seen this happen when I am 100% certain there were no Windows updates waiting to install. Additionally, if I push the power button while at the black screen with the back light on, it will immediately turn off. Normally I have it set to require the six-second press. If Windows had begun to load at all, acpi would make me hold the button down. Additionally, I know from watching other boots that as soon as Windows starts to load it disables the broken internal screen, as I have set it to do in it's new HTPC role. So now I think the machine is sitting at some kind of boot menu.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to see anything at all on the built-in screen, and it seems the machine will not use the hdmi port for bios/setup.

I'll add that I believe the Dell is in Legacy boot mode, as I believe that's how I got things working as an HTPC in the first place. Before the screen had died completely, and I could sometimes get a flickering view, I installed Windows on another legacy mode machine, transferred the disk, and set the disk as the Legacy boot target. I suspect re-installing Windows from scratch again would fix this, but that will be tough to replicate now without any screen at all.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does this laptop have a VGA port? You may be able to connect it to a VGA compatible monitor to see what's happening on screen during the incomplete boot. (YMMV as in my experience, on some computers this will work, on others it will not, but it's worth a try)

Comment: There is no vga port.

Comment: Are there any video outputs other than the HDMI that you're already using? If so, what are they?

Comment: Also, have you considered replacing the screen? It's usually not particularly difficult, and the part is often pretty cheap.

Comment: HDMI and the internal screen are my only options. I'm gonna try a different hdmi screen than the TV, though. It's possible there is signal out the hdmi port, and the TV just can't use it.

Comment: I took it most of the way apart before deciding to convert it for HTPC, and in this case, replacing the screen was not at all trivial. Possible, maybe, but I'm not confident enough I could put it back together again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to remove the display assembly completely. While I'm not comfortable removing the display assembly **and** removing the panel from the assembly **and** installing the new panel in the assembly **and** putting everything together again, I am able to complete just that first step.

The result is no wifi antenna and no built-in display... but that's okay. I already had the system connected via the wired ethernet port, and removing the display has solved my issue: I am now able to watch the boot up process in full on the TV, and thus get past any issue there. Surprisingly, I haven't yet even had the need, which means it was likely something in the failing display that caused the boot issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot from USB, try a Live Linux release, e.g. [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0). During setup, it should find the HDMI drivers. Linux should do well as a media server.

*Catch 22*: if you need to enter BIOS with a blank screen, that would be difficult -- though **not** impossible. Have someone with the same model record each key-press to reach BIOS, to change boot order, etc.

Another alternative would be to actually install Linux while the HDD is in the alternate laptop.

Comment: If I could do this, I would have already fixed the Windows install.